# Creating links popup text

Tags: support, markdown, hyperlinks

When clicking the URL icon with nothing selected you get a box that says this:

> http://example.com/ "optional title"

So i wrote in

> http://www.msdn.com "My link text"

However, this produced the following:

> [enter link description here][1]
>
> [1]: http://www.msdn.com "My link text"

What have i done wrong?

P.S. I nearly always write my title, select it then create the link, however just wondering what's up with this use case.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The 'title' is actually the `title` HTML attribute of the link, which is reflected in the browser usually as a popup that appears when you hover over the link. For example:

> **[Hover me!](http://example.com)**

Which appears on my computer as:

[image: Title popup example]

Comment: Thanks, will accept when i can.